# A quasi-analytic nowhere analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2781333/515542). The set-up for this question is somewhat different. For $n \geq 1,$ let $M_n =  (n \log n)^n$ and set $M_0=1.$ Say that an infinitely differentiable real function $f$ belongs to the quasi-analytic class $C\{M_n\}$if there are constants $\beta_f,B_f$ depending only on $f,$ such that 
$$||D^n f||_\infty \leq \beta_f (B_f)^n M_n \qquad \forall  n \geq 0,$$ where $||-||_\infty$ is the supremum norm on $\mathbb{R}.$

In the book "Numerical methods in the study of Critical phenomena", pg. 30-32 , I have been told that the function $$b(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp(-2^{n}/n) \cos(2^nx)$$ lies in $C\{M_n\},$ and that it is nowhere analytic. There is a purported proof that $b \in C\{M_n\}$ in the book "Numerical methods in the study of critical phenomena" (which is reproduced in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2782989/515542)). However, I strongly suspect that there are typos in the proof, and that it might even be wrong in some places. This makes the supposed proof unreadable to me.

So my question is:
How do I show that $b(x) \in C\{M_n\}?$ Can the proof given in "Numerical methods in the study of Critical phenomena" be salvaged?

Comment: "I strongly suspect that there are typos in the proof" Why don't you point out what you think are typos / what you don't understand / what you think is wrong with the proof .

Comment: Also: why is this question not a duplicate of [Proof that a function is quasi-analytic. Error in paper?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782989/proof-that-a-function-is-quasi-analytic-error-in-paper) ??

Comment: @Winther In that question, I ask to help with the proof directly. In this I am OK with other methods. I think the question is different, but if it is a duplicate, please merge.

Comment: One thing I can not see why it is true:
Why is $\theta_n(r) <-r \log 2 /2 ?$ The right hand side of the inequality above doesn ot seem to be negative for large values of $r,$ so I do not see why it follows from that inequality.

Comment: Wait. There is an additional constraint here. A few lines above they write $n > N_r$ so $n$ is constrained to be $n > N_r \sim \log(r)$ (does seem to be a typo in definition of $N_r$). Thus when $r$ is large $n$ is also large so $-2^n$ will dominate over $r\log(2)$ making it negative.