# An upper bound for an infinite series, indexed by $k,$ independent of $k?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $$f(k) = \dfrac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n e^{-\frac{2^n}{nk}}}{k \log k}$$
where $k \geq 2$ is an integer. From numerical investigation, and from reasons stemming from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783694/a-quasi-analytic-nowhere-analytic-function?noredirect=1&lq=1), I believe that there is a positive constant $B < \infty$ such that $$|f(k)| < B$$  for all $k.$

My question is:
How do I prove that there exists such a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for $\eta > 0$

$$
\eta^2 e^{-\eta} \lt 1 \Rightarrow \eta e^{-\eta}\lt \frac{1}{\eta}
$$

then

$$
\sum_{\nu = 1}^{\infty}\nu\left(\frac{2^{\nu}}{\nu k}\right)e^{-\frac{2^{\nu}}{\nu k}} \lt \sum_{\nu=1}^{\infty}\nu\left(\frac{\nu k}{2^{\nu}}\right) = k\sum_{\nu=1}^{\infty}\frac{\nu^2}{2^{\nu}}
$$

We know that

$$
\sum_{\nu = 1}^{\infty}\nu^2x^{\nu} \lt M \ \ \mbox{for } |x| < 1
$$

For $x = 2^{-1}$ we have $M = 6$ So we can conclude that

$$
f(k) \lt \frac{N}{\log (k)}
$$